# Path to image under MVC5 Area

Tags: c#, .net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am pretty new to MVC5 and I am trying to have a *Content* folder locally under one of my Areas. Unfortunately I cannot seem to get the image to render in the output since the path becomes incorrect(?) and I can´t figure out how to correctly reference it.

In my solution I the following:

```
ProjectX
  Areas
     Area1
        Controller
           Area1DefaultController
        Content
           Images
               image1.png
        Views
               View1.cshtml
```

In my View i use this:

```
@Url.Content("~/Areas/Area1/Content/Images/image1.png")
```

I have also tried..

```
@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/image1.png")
@Url.Content("/Content/Images/image1.png")
@Url.Content("Content/Images/image1.png")
```

..and the result in all cases are broken images (i.e. the path is incorrect). I guess the routing somehow prevents the image from being retrieved but I can´t figure out how to fix the problem.

This is my area registration:

```
public class Area1Registration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get { return "Area1"; }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Area_default",
            "Area/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Area1Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: ReSharper is able to resolve the path in the markup.

**How can I find my resources under Content?**

Comment: Why are you putting static content like image in areas?

Comment: Because they are specific to the area they reside in and there might be images with the same name in the "globally" static folder. Let´s just say that it is a design issue I am not in control of. Do you know how to resolve the actual issue?

Comment: Personally I would put use a folder structor such as `/content/area1` etc but in your example `/Areas/Area1/Content/Images/image1.png` should work fine, what happens when you type that URL into the browser?

Comment: I receive a 404. ("HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for..").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason I received a 404 was the BlockViewHandler in the Area1 `web.config`. I created a new web.config and placed in my `Static` folder to solve the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>  
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler" />     
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```